# PowerShell Where-Object Boolean and pipeline output (to find duplicate AD machines between domains)

Tags: powershell, pipe, pipeline

Weird output coming through from what I would expect. How do I find out what I'm doing wrong?

I am trying to find out [Active Directory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_Directory) machines that exist in two domains and find the inactive one between them (the one that has logged on with the oldest time).

Further up the script, all computers with lastlogontimestamp and some other properties are pulled from Active Directory into Arrays DomainAComputers and DomainBComputers; the following is to find out which machine is the one we should be removing.

```
# Match machines between domains to find duplicates - Works fine.
$Duplicates = $Computers | ? {($DomainAComputers.name -match $_.name) -and ($DomainBComputers.name -match $_.name)} 

# Create a custom array with only the INACTIVE machine between the 2 domains
$DuplicateInactive = @()

# Loop through each machine
Foreach ($comp in $Duplicates){   
$DomApc = $DomainAComp | ? {$_.name -eq $comp.name} #pull single comp entry from DomA array
$DomBpc = $DomainBComp | ? {$_.name -eq $comp.name} #pull single comp entry from DomB array

# Compare to see if DomA pc is not in use.
$DupDomAinactive = $DomApc | ? {$DomApc.lastlogontimestamp.DateTime -le $DomBpc.lastlogontimestamp.DateTime}
# Compare to see if DomB pc is not in use   
$DupDomBinactive = $DomBpc | ? {$DomBpc.lastlogontimestamp.DateTime -le $DomApc.lastlogontimestamp.DateTime} 

#output results to custom array
$DuplicateInactive += $DupDomAInactive
$DuplicateInactive += $DupDomBInactive
}
```

Issue: If I do a query of
`$DomApc.lastlogontimestamp.DateTime -le $DomBpc.lastlogontimestamp.DateTime`, the result is true; and the opposite is true for `DomBpc -le DomApc`, it returns false.
(Example, `DomA - 27/04/2018 4:22:37 PM is less than DomB - 7/05/2018 12:18:06 PM` - returns TRUE.)

I would then expect that the one returning true would pass its result back to $DupDomAinactive, and get added to `$DuplicateInactive`, however this does not seem to be the case.

From a total of 54, `$duplicateinactive.count` shows 54, however an output of `$duplicateinactive` shows around 10 entries (5 machines twice). I would expect that there would be exactly half returning true, therefore 27 results.

What am I doing wrong and is there a much easier way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks; I think there was multiple issues with how I was doing it; I found that as I am trying to do a Boolean operation, putting it through an if statement was the best way to go (instead of straight through a where-object which I suspect was doing some weird things with the $true\$false results passed back).

Also using two separate outputs for the two domains was needed; and using Sort-object to get rid of the duplicates in the output (as it does comparison twice, once for each domain).

I used LotPing's idea of using one pipeline, but it was missing the crucial part of comparing domains (the `-le` filter). Final output:

```
$DomADup = @()
$DomBDup = @()
$Computers |
Where-Object {($DomAComputers.name -match $_.name) -and
              ($DomBComputers.name -match $_.name)} |
    ForEach-Object {
        $Comp = $_
        $DomApc = $DomAComputers | ? {$_.name -eq $comp.name}
        $DomBpc = $DomBComputers | ? {$_.name -eq $comp.name}
        if($DomApc.lastlogontimestamp.DateTime -le $DomBpc.lastlogontimestamp.DateTime) {$DomADup +=$DomApc}
        if($DomBpc.lastlogontimestamp.DateTime -le $DomApc.lastlogontimestamp.DateTime) {$DomBDup +=$DomBpc}
            }
$DomAToDelete = $DomADup | sort-object -property Name -unique
$DomBToDelete = $DomBDup | sort-object -property Name -unique
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd gather the computername and LastLogout dates in a table first.

```
$Duplicates = $Computers |
    Where-Object {($DomainAComputers.name -match $_.name) -and
                  ($DomainBComputers.name -match $_.name)} |
        ForEach-Object {
            $Comp = $_
            $DomApc = $DomainAComp | ? {$_.name -eq $comp}
            $DomBpc = $DomainBComp | ? {$_.name -eq $comp}
            [PSCustomObject]@{
                'Computer' = $_
                'DomALastLogOut' = $DomApc.lastlogontimestamp.DateTime
                'DomBLastLogOut' = $DomBpc.lastlogontimestamp.DateTime
            }
        }
$Duplicates
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the current object (`$PSItem` or `$_`) and not the whole object array (`$DomApc` or `$DomBpc`) in the `Where` (`? {$_...}`) clause.

In other words:

```
#compare to see if DomA pc is not in use.
$DupDomAinactive = $DomApc | ? {$DomApc.lastlogontimestamp.DateTime -le $DomBpc.lastlogontimestamp.DateTime}
#compare to see if DomB pc is not in use    
$DupDomBinactive = $DomBpc | ? {$DomBpc.lastlogontimestamp.DateTime -le $DomApc.lastlogontimestamp.DateTime}
```

should be:

```
#compare to see if DomA pc is not in use.
$DupDomAinactive = $DomApc | ? {$_.lastlogontimestamp.DateTime -le $DomBpc.lastlogontimestamp.DateTime}
#compare to see if DomB pc is not in use    
$DupDomBinactive = $DomBpc | ? {$_.lastlogontimestamp.DateTime -le $DomApc.lastlogontimestamp.DateTime}
```